# listbox вывод items

Tags: c#

Как по клику на кнопке добавить в listbox запись и через 10 секунд добавить другую запись. Когда выполняю этот код, то записи появляются одновременно через 10 сек после нажатия на кнопку:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Начат процесс удаления");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
listBox1.Items.Add("Закончен процесс удаления");
```

Как сделать появление записей по очереди с задержкой ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);` блокирует главный(UI) поток, поэтому никаких изменений Вы и не видите. Ставьте таймер на 10 секунд, по завершении которого добавляйте второй элемент. Но запомните — никогда не блокируйте главный поток.

Comment: Так же можно использовать `await Task.Delay(10000);`

Comment: @Alexis, можно и так, согласен.